# Remove Halo Remodel Cans

Tags: recessed-lighting

I've got several 4" Halo Remodel MR16 cans (model is 528-786 or 528-7S6) in one of my rooms - plasterboard ceiling, first floor, no attic access. I want to replace them with wafer lights because the cans have an integrated transformer.

I'm unsure what these cans look like in their removed state, and I'm having trouble pulling them out. I believe they're supposed to angle in and out, but I cannot get them to drop down far enough.

I'm looking for the best route forward here and thought I would look for the wisdom of the group. I feel like I have 3 options:

1. Figure out how to remove the light correctly and replace it with 4" wafer lights (preferred method),
2. Buy a plasterboard adjustable hole saw, carefully enlarge the hole to 6.25", and remove the light,
3. Continue trying to force it out and hope I don't damage the plasterboard too much.

Edit: adding photo of product label.

[image: product sticker]

[image: The exterior of the light]

[[image: interior of the light3]

[[image: another sticker in the light4]

Comment: I added a picture of the product sticker. From the outside, it really just looks like white trim with a deep 4" can. It does have the tabs like this one: https://www.cooperlighting.com/global/brands/halo/875470/h245ricat-series

I get those down and am able to drop it down about 1/2", but it doesn't really go from there.

Comment: Looks like 528.756 *to me,* but it also looks like the UL issue number, not the fixture model number. And UL's public database is striking out on that for me.

Comment: Is it possible to push these up entirely into the ceiling? That could give you room to cut them apart with tin snips or similar.

Comment: Added another couple of photos above. I'm really not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Kinda looks to me like those tabs should be able to be pried back into the can or something.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got back to this over the weekend and successfully replaced all three. The trick to removing them was to lower the tabs, then to push  the lower part back up and remove the bracket altogether. Once that was done, I was able to remove the transformer and pull it out of the ceiling in two parts - housing and transformer. The first one took about 4 hours to pull and replace with a canless 6", the other two took 1.5 total.